# Migrating hstore datatypes from PostgreSQL to CockroachDB

Tags: database, postgresql, cockroachdb

I'm considering migrating some PostgreSQL databases to CockroachDB. One application I have uses the PostgreSQL [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/hstore.html) datatype.

Is there an equivalent way to store this data in CockroachDB?

If not, what is the best-practice for mapping this datatype with as little change to the application code as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB has a [`jsonb`](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/jsonb.html) type that is quite similar to PostgreSQL's so you could convert your `hstore`s to `jsonb` objects (i.e. an `hstore` like `'a=>x, b=>y'` would become `{"a":"x", "b":"y"}` on `jsonb`).

The most common (probably) operator you'd be using with `hstore` would be `->` to access a value based on a key. With `jsonb`, `->` gives you a `jsonb` result so you'd want to switch to `->>` which gives you a string (just like `->` with `hstore`). The `@>` operator behaves similarly with `jsonb` (both CockroachDB's and PostgreSQL's) as it does with `hstore` but some changes would be needed. Any `hstore_...` functions would, of course, need to be replaced.

CockroachDB's `jsonb` is very similar to PostgreSQL's. Also, `hstore` is sort of deprecated in favor of `jsonb` in PostgreSQL. So you might want to replace `hstore` with `jsonb` inside PostgreSQL before trying to move to CockroachDB.